# How to fix padding Twitter Bootstrap cell tables when using colspan

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to create study table, using Twitter Bootstrap 3 as css framework.
I used `<td colspan="2">` for a hour cell and `<td>` for half hour cell, so it I have 17 cells(8 hours plus 1 cell for day)

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>#</th>
         <th colspan="2">9.000 - 10.00</th>
         <th colspan="2">10.00 - 11.00</th>
         <th colspan="2">11.00 - 12.00</th>
         <th colspan="2">12.00 - 13.00</th>
         <th colspan="2">13.00 - 14.00</th>
         <th colspan="2">14.00 - 15.00</th>
         <th colspan="2">15.00 - 16.00</th>
         <th colspan="2">16.00 - 17.00</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Mon</td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="6">ITE-301, S1<br >A603, 86</td>
         <td colspan="3"></td>
         <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="6">ITE-204, S1<br >D201, 81</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Tuえ</td>
         <td colspan="4"></td>
         <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="6">ITE-302, S1<br >A602, 40</td>
         <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="6">HUM-111, S1<br >B202, 81</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Wed</td>
         <td></td>
         <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="3">MSC-202, S1<br >A313, 41</td>
         <td colspan="3"></td>
         <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="3">JPN-202, S1<br >D503, 30</td>
         <td colspan="6"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I expected it to be rendered like this.
[image]

The first subject should start at center of 9 - 10am column(at 9.30am) but what I got is this.

[image]

it start at 10.00 as if `td` before it was set to `colspan="2"` but the remainder is work fine.

I tried to disable each css property and found that if I disable `width: 100%` at `.table` and set `padding: 8px 0px` to `.table>tbody>tr>td` it is rendered properly but quite ugly.
[image]
Is there any workaround to get table I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give up `td` and `th` padding if you want this to work. It's not a problem of Bootstrap itself, but of the way html `tables` were designed. Back when they were made, CSS was simply not around yet. All the styling was done inline or via attributes. In our case, with the help of the `cellpadding` table attribute, which is no longer supported in HTML5 (and which Chrome has dropped support for ~v.20-ish).

So I guess you need

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
    padding: 0;
}
```

for this to work. Now, if you want your padding back, you will need to wrap all the cell contents in divs and apply padding to those (i.e.:`.table td>div, .table th>div{padding: 8px;}`). 
That's the ***practical* solution**.

**The *right* solution**, however is NOT to use `<table>`s for layouting. They are designed for tabular data.

Here's a dirty lil' fix, using jQuery and CSS, that dynamically adds div wrappers to all your non-empty `td`s and `th`s contents. The `text-align:center` rule is not needed for it to work, I just added it as I thought it looked nicer.

```js
$('.table th, .table td').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html() ? $('<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>') : '');
});
```

```css
table.table>tbody>tr>td,table.table>tbody>tr>th,
table.table>tfoot>tr>td,table.table>tfoot>tr>th,
table.table>thead>tr>td,table.table>thead>tr>th {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table td > div,.table th>div {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th colspan="2">9.000 - 10.00</th>
      <th colspan="2">10.00 - 11.00</th>
      <th colspan="2">11.00 - 12.00</th>
      <th colspan="2">12.00 - 13.00</th>
      <th colspan="2">13.00 - 14.00</th>
      <th colspan="2">14.00 - 15.00</th>
      <th colspan="2">15.00 - 16.00</th>
      <th colspan="2">16.00 - 17.00</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="6">ITE-301, S1
        <br>A603, 86</td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="6">ITE-204, S1
        <br>D201, 81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tue</td>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
      <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="6">ITE-302, S1
        <br>A602, 40</td>
      <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="6">HUM-111, S1
        <br>B202, 81</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Wed</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="3">MSC-202, S1
        <br>A313, 41</td>
      <td colspan="3"></td>
      <td class="study-table-hightlight" colspan="3">JPN-202, S1
        <br>D503, 30</td>
      <td colspan="6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also as [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/j0f0L8o8/), you you prefer (I know I do:).

Comment: Thank you very much, I used script that you provided and set text align in each column to center, it perfectly align.